# Hamburger menu drop down on low width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have navbar with few items and hamburger icon that should be displayed on low width, in this time navbar items should hide. With the button i want to change their display to bo flex and flex-direction set to column, so items will display vertically. I am trying to use this function, could you suggest me something ?

Here is the code :

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
let menu = document.getElementsByClassName('hammburger-links')[0];


btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    menu.classList.toggle('openmenu');
});
```

```css
.slider .hammburger-menu {
  width: 16px;
  height: 14px;
  border: 0;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

@media (max-width: 1425px) {
  .slider .hammburger-menu {
    display: inline;
  }
  .slider .hammburger-menu div {
    background-color: #202124;
    display: block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 4px 0;
  }
}

.slider .hammburger-links {
  padding: 0 1.250em;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.slider .hammburger-links a {
  padding: 0 1.500em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Helvetica", Arial;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #a6adb4;
}

@media (max-width: 1425px) {
  .slider .hammburger-links a {
    display: none;
  }
}

.slider .hammburger-links .under-home {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.5em;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  background: #F6F8F9;
  min-width: 12.5em;
  min-height: 12.5em;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.slider .hammburger-links .under-home a {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.slider .hammburger-links.openhome {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.slider .hammburger-links.openmenu a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
            <div class="hammburger-menu" id="btn">
                <div class="one"></div>
                <div class="two"></div>
                <div class="three"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="hammburger-links" id="menu">
                <a href="" id="home">HOME</a>
                <div class="under-home">
                    <a href="">WORLD NEWS</a>
                    <a href="">TRAVEL</a>
                    <a href="">TECHNOLOGY</a>
                    <a href="">CITY</a>
                    <a href="">CULTURE</a>
                    <a href="">MORE...</a>
                </div>
                <a href="">DISCOVERY</a>
                <a href="">PHOTOS</a>
                <a href="">CONTACT</a>
                <img src="images/navbar-img.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array. So you want to do `let menu = document.getElementsByClassName('hammburger-links')[0];` or get the element by id (menu).

Doing that should add the desired class to the #menu element, but your CSS also has a problem. Your CSS selector `.slider .hammburger-links .openmenu` doesn't select anything. That selector looks for an element .openmenu that is a descendant of an element .hammburger-links, that is a descendant of element .slider. You need the element that belongs to classes hammburger-links *and* openmenu. The selector looks like this: `.slider .hammburger-links.openmenu`

However, that still doesn't reveal the menu elements. I found that changing the selector again to target child anchor elements (`.slider .hammburger-links.openmenu a`) did the trick, but you may want to go about that differently depending on how you want to implement it.

Comment: Could you explain how does it help ?

Comment: It's the first thing I noticed. There's a problem with your CSS as well. Check my edit.

Comment: It still doesn't address the vertical column aspect of the question, but it seems to me that getting your javascript working should be enough to get you unstuck. If you're still having issues with doing flex stuff I can offer some help, but I'll admit I'm not super familiar with flex.

Comment: It should look like this ? I have edited code snippet. I am really confused now.

Comment: Change `menu.classList.toggle('openmenu a');` to `menu.classList.toggle('openmenu');`. That part was fine.